# Bootstrap buttons not taking effect in phonegap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I'm using Twitter bootstrap's bootstrap.min.css for styling my phonegap app. But I do not see the desired UI of DOM elements affected by bootstrap. For example, in [Base CSS](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) it is shown that `btn btn-primary` classed button is colored blue and has some gradient on it. Looks nice. But this thing looks so ugly gray colored if I run this on emulator. Why is that so? Isn't bootstrap good for phonegap?

**ADDING CODE AND SCREENSHOT**
[image: Unpleasant UI rendering]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Call the cab</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/heartcode.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad();initialize()">
    <div id="wrapper" class="container row-fluid ">
    <div id="headerdiv" class="span12">
                <header style="vertical-align:middle;">
                <h1>App Name</h1>
                 </header>
    </div><!--End of header-->


    <div id="inputs" class="row-fluid"> 
            <form action="file:///android_asset/www/pickup.html"  onsubmit="return saveInputs()" class="form-inline form-actions">  
            <input type="text" id="pickup"  onblur="unlockDestiny();codeAddress(this.value)" class="input-block-level"/>
            <input type="text" id="destiny"  onblur="codeAddress(this.value)" class="input-block-level"/>
            <label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="">
Remember this
</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </form>
    </div><!--End of inputs-->

    </div><!--End of wrapper-->
     </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a specific example accompanied by code and possibly a screenshot?

Comment: Hey I've added both the things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you double checked that the path to the CSS files is correct, and that there's nothing in css/custom.css that is overriding the Bootstrap button styling?

Comment: Yes!I have. Moreover, that css contains almost nothing.

Comment: Are you checking in an emulator or has your app actually been deployed?

Comment: No I'm Checking in an emulator only. Haven't deployed yet on any device. Ok So are you saying it will run as expected on device rather than emulator?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's worth checking. A similar thing has happened to me in with Bootstrap styling in a different situation.

Comment: no it doesn't ...I have similar issue...and tried on real device both android 2.3 and android 4.0 ...using the latest version of bootstrap 3.0 I believe... Issue filed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931070/bootstrap-3-0-on-android-phonegap