# bootstrap 3.0 on android phonegap

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap-3

is there any known issue of bootstrap 3.0 (the latest one) on android phonegap. I am able to see the buttons nicely on firefox (and on same resolution as on phone) but when the binary is installed on the phone the buttons do not render....

is this a known issue ?

Following is my simple template:

```
 <div id="mcontent">
     <div id="swrapper">
         <div id="islider">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Mrs</a>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Ms.</a>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Mr.</a>
             </div>
             <form>
                 <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
                 <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                 <p><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
                 <p>Must be at least 8 characters long</p>
                 <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                 <input type="password" placeholder="Password repeat">
                 <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-  block">Submit</button></p>
                 <p><span id="dclaimer">By registering you confirm that you accept our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy</span></p>
             </form>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seeing this with Bootstrap 3 and Cordova as well... https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues might be a more effective place for this convo.

Comment: I have the same problem; can't find the exact problem on github but there is a similar issue where justified buttons won't render as a device is rotated: the issue is marked as 'won't be fixed'!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I have had the same issue. I believe this is down to jquery mobile. As when i removed it, it worked

Removing just the css of jquery mobile seems to keep jquery mobile functionality and allow bs to work